# linux + how to identify if file is pointed by link/s

Tags: linux, solaris, shell-scripting, ksh

I create new file called - 192.9.200.1

```
    touch 192.9.200.1
```

then I create new link that will be pointed to 192.9.200.1 file

```
    ln -s 192.9.200.1 file
```

so finally I get:

```
     ls -ltr /tmp

    -rw-r--r--  1 root root        0 May  8 19:39 192.9.200.1
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       11 May  8 19:39 file -> 192.9.200.1
```

but when I do **ls -ltr** on the 192.9.200.1 file I cant see if other link/s is point to 192.9.200.1

```
     ls -ltr 192.9.200.1
      -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 May  8 19:39 192.9.200.1
```

what the way to identify if file or directory have link/s ,

- remark I don't want to do **ls -ltr under /tmp  directory** to find links !

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to know if other files are symlinking to a file . ls -l under /tmp wouldn't work anyway, since symlinks could be placed to other dirs than /tmp .

Comment: Well there is a really ugly way.  Scan the entire filesystem looking for links.  I suspect you could work something out with `find`, `-type -l`, and `-lname`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A symbolic link is similar to a shortcut in Windows. It's a entry in the file system that points to another file. The destination file is not touched and no change is made to the original files metadata - it does not know that it has been linked to.

You will not be able to tell if a file has symbolic links pointing at it just by looking at information from ls.

Hard links, however, increment the link count on the file system which can be seen in a directory listing. If you hard link two files to the same data, both will show a link count of 2

Answer (score 4):

> what the way to identify if file or directory have link/s

You can do like this:

```
find / -lname "filename"
```

Comment: the problem is if I need to check 100 files under / so it will take allot of time ............

Comment: @yael 100 files are checked very fast. Or did you mean 100 TB of files?

Comment: @ott-- 100TB of files can checked very fast too if they're big files (of course if they're all 1B files you've got the opposite situation: Checking 100 trillion files would certainly take a long time :-)